# 95%-ile calculations : Can I use "unused bandwidth" for external backups?

Tags: networking, bandwidth

My datacenter is charging me Mbits with 95 percentile calculations. I usually pay for 90mbits every month because of traffic spikes that I have every morning. Those traffic spikes are somewhere between 100 and 200mbit every morning for somewhere between 1 and 2 hours. During the rest of the day traffic is always below 40mbit.

So if I get this right every 5 minutes my datacenter is checking my bandwidth and at the end of the month the 5% biggest measurements get dropped. The next value is what I'll have to pay and for me this is about 90mbits because of the traffic spikes every morning.

Now I need to send backups to an external site. But traffic is very expensive here. I would like to find out if there's a way to do this without increasing my current bandwidth costs.

I'm thinking about this method:

Start backups at night, when traffic is low and rate limit my backups using the linux "tc" command. I can then have the rate adjusted every 30 seconds or so. I can adjust the speed on the fly and write some daemon that gets the current internet uplink throughput rate from my router.

So, this daemon could get the current upload throughput rate from my router every 30 seconds and adjust the backup upload speed so that the total bandwidth never exceeds 80mbits. And limit it to 1mbit at those moments when traffic is already >80mbits.

If I'm correct this way my backups will not cause any additional spikes and will not increase my bandwidth costs.

What are your opinions? Should this work?

Comment: It sounds like you are starting to outgrow your current datacenter setup and need your own dedicated network.  That said, you can certainly rate limit using `tc` for the port or IP's your backups software uses during off-hours provided your backup software isn't having problems with that and assuming your backups actually complete daily.   Incomplete backups are bad backups as I am sure you know.  I would verify with them that this will bring you below their threshold and that the daily sum won't still be a problem.

Comment: I could use rsync to send local backups to the remote location and I don't think rsync will have problems with low speeds.But I'm not sure how much data I'll be able to send over daily. I might not be able to send them all in a single day but then again, it's actually okay to only have a full backup on the remote site every 2 or 3 days or so.

Comment: It would also solve the problem if you can make the backups complete in less than 72 minutes. Which ironically means you would need the spikes to be even higher. But if you can smear the backups over several hours and leave the 5% spike allowance to unexpected traffic, that would probably be better, and more in line with the intention of the pricing model. But how did you get the 80Mbit number? The right value depends on your traffic patterns, but I would have expected a much lower number.